# setup django to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to connect django to mysql database on windows. I tried to install >pip install MySQL-python but i'm getting an error . I added in the file settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'toto',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5220',
    }
}
```

and when I run the server i got this error : `Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'`
 I'm using python 3.5 and django 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Installing  MySQL-python should work.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 0):

When i got this error, it went away with:

```
Sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev

pip install mysqlclient
```

Edit:

To get it to work in my Windows development environment, i had to download mysqlclient from here
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

and then used pip to install:

```
pip install c:\users\myself\mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```